# Connect report footer section with details section in one page

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, footer

I have a report that print a certificate that contains:

- Headletter
- Introduction for the certificate .
- Table head that will be repeated if there is more than one page
- Table details that got the items that vary from one to 100 item.
- Manager’s stamp and signature
- ReportFooter which includes the company details.

My problem are:

1. When I have 25 items in the table, I get the 25 items in the first page and the signature and stamp in the second page.

   What I want is to tell MS Access somehow to move 5 items to the next page of the signature and the stamp ( ReporFooter) to the next page.
2. How can I make the (PageHeader Section) above the (ReportHeader Section) in the first page, so I can put the letterhead image in the pageHeaderSection.

Comment: Try increasing the height of ReportFooter (i.e., gap at bottom or top), forcing records to next page.

Comment: PageHeader cannot be above ReportHeader. Try setting report PageHeader property to `Not with Rpt Hdr`.